# Gradle docker plugin bind windows host share

Tags: windows, docker, gradle

I am using https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin for connecting to docker from gradle. I have the following task to create a container on windows:

```
task "docker-container-create"(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    description = "Create Docker container"
    group "${dockerGroup}-container"

    ext {
        dockerTag = project.dockerTag 
    }

    targetImageId { "${dockerRepository}:${project.dockerTag}" as String }
    delegate.containerName = containerName

    portBindings = ["80:${project.dockerExposedPort}"]

    env = ["GRAILS_ENV=development"]
    cmd = ["--app.dockerContainerName=${containerName}"]

    if(!new File("${project.projectDir}/data").exists()) new File("${project.projectDir}/data").mkdirs()

    binds [
        ("${project.projectDir}/data" as String):'/app/data',
        ("${project.projectDir}/src/main/config/" as String):'/app/config',
    ]
}
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
{"message":"invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/c/Users/**/parts/data:rw'"}
```

I am running Docker version `17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)-stable`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently windows mount points should be defined in the form `//C/<folder>` as stated in the release notes of this version:

```
Fix Mount compatibility when mounting drives with `-v //c/...`, now mounted in /host_mnt/c in the LinuxKit VM. Fixes [docker/for-win#1509](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1509), [docker/for-win#1516](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1516),
```

I created a small helper utility in the gradle build file:

```
    def volumes = {volumes -> volumes.collectEntries{k,v ->
        if(k.contains('\\')){
            k = "//${k.replaceAll('\\\\','/')}"
            k = k.replaceAll(':','')
        }
        [(k):v]
    }}
```

So the config now reads:

```
task "docker-container-create"(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    description = "Create Docker container"
    group "${dockerGroup}-container"

    ext {
        dockerTag = project.dockerTag 
    }

    targetImageId { "${dockerRepository}:${project.dockerTag}" as String }
    delegate.containerName = containerName

    portBindings = ["80:${project.dockerExposedPort}"]

    env = ["GRAILS_ENV=development"]
    cmd = ["--app.dockerContainerName=${containerName}"]

    if(!new File("${project.projectDir}/data").exists()) new File("${project.projectDir}/data").mkdirs()

    def volumes = {volumes -> volumes.collectEntries{k,v ->
        if(k.contains('\\')){
            k = "//${k.replaceAll('\\\\','/')}"
            k = k.replaceAll(':','')
        }
        [(k):v]
    }}

    binds = volumes([
        ("${project.projectDir}/data" as String):'/app/data',
        ("${project.projectDir}/src/main/config/" as String):'/app/config',
    ])
}
```

This works.